# AWS: Resizing a RESERVED t2.medium to a m3.large. How pricing works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to hire a reserved instance in Amazon EC2 to host an application.

What really drives me the choose of it, is the RAM capacity. I know I will be running this APP for years, but I do not know how hardware requirements will be changing in the future.

So, lets say I hire a t2.medium reserved instance for a year, and in 6 month I have a boom of demand and I realize I have to migrate to a m3.large.

Do I need to give up 6 month of the already paid t2.medium instance ? Or I can just pay the difference for the 6 month between the t2.medium and the m3.large instance ?

I think flexibility is what really make AWS interesting... but I need to be able to scale up at a reasonable cost...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give up the 6 months - you can use it for something else, or sell it right on the amazon reserved instance marketplace. If you price it right, which means slighly below what amazon charges, you can usually offload it pretty quickly. I buy a lot of 'used' instances this way because you can get  the discounted reserved instance price, but get shorter terms, i.e. the 6 months in your case.

BTW: When you talk about scaling on amazon you are generally talking about scaling by adding more instances - which is your other option. If you architect it correctly, you don't have to upgrade to a large from a medium, you buy another medium (or small), or possibly even used spot instances, to fill that gap in performance.

If you upgrade from med to large, because traffic picks up, then if traffic goes back down you are stuck paying for a large when a medium would do. Consider designing your app to spread its work across a number of instances, and have that number scale up and down in response to changes in workload - that is going to end up being the best solution for you - if possible in your circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you cant do this with a single RI and also cant do it between different instance families.

Relevant sections of the EC2 FAQ:

> An RI is associated with a specific
> instance family for the duration of the RI term; however, you can
> change from one instance type (e.g., c3.large) to another (e.g.,
> c3.xlarge) in the same family, if it is a Linux/UNIX RI.
>
> You can consolidate multiple smaller reservations into a single larger
> reservation. For example, an RI for 8 m1.smalls at $0.014/hour each
> can be modified to create an RI for 4 m1.mediums at $0.028/hour each,
> 2 m1.larges at $0.056/hour each, or 1 m1.xlarge at $0.112/hour.
>
> You can divide a larger reservation into multiple smaller reservations.
> For example, an RI for 1 m1.xlarge at $0.112/hour can be modified to
> create an RI for 2 m1.larges at $0.056/hour each, 4 m1.mediums at
> $0.028/hour each, or 8 m1.smalls at $0.014/hour each.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/

Like E.J. Brennan says, you should scale your application horizontally by adding more instances of the same size or sell off unsused RIs on the market.

Comment: About the RI consolidation, is it something AWS billing does it for you automatically? Or do I need to go to the ec2->Reserved Instance and modify myself?